# MySQL Server restarts after trigger execution

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger in MySQL that is causing the MySQL server to restart each time it's triggered. This started happening after the version 8.0.22 update a day ago. My trigger is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER max_client_invoice_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON client_invoices FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE vMax int(11);

SELECT IFNULL(max(client_invoice_id),0) from client_invoices where client_operating_unit_id = NEW.client_operating_unit_id INTO vMax;

SET NEW.client_invoice_id = vMax+1;

END
```

Is there anything I am missing due to the recent update, or any better and efficient ways of achieving the same goal if I can't seem to find the cause of the server crashes?

I have also checked the logs and this is what I found:

```
06:03:02 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x7f08e4921bd0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f09c8254c70 thread_stack 0x46000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x2194f3d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x313) [0xff55f3]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf630) [0x7f09d5633630]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Item_splocal::this_item()+0x14) [0x111fce4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Item_sp_variable::val_int()+0x13) [0x111fb63]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Item_func_plus::int_op()+0x1d) [0x11aafdd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Item_func_numhybrid::val_int()+0x191) [0x11ad541]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Item::save_in_field_inner(Field*, bool)+0x125) [0x11259c5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Item::save_in_field(Field*, bool)+0x53) [0x113ef03]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Item_trigger_field::set_value(THD*, sp_rcontext*, Item**)+0x76) [0x113f136]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_instr_set_trigger_field::exec_core(THD*, unsigned int*)+0x90) [0xe38a80]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_lex_instr::reset_lex_and_exec_core(THD*, unsigned int*, bool)+0x60c) [0xe39b1c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_lex_instr::validate_lex_and_execute_core(THD*, unsigned int*, bool)+0x9a) [0xe3a55a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_head::execute(THD*, bool)+0x5d3) [0xe311c3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_head::execute_trigger(THD*, MYSQL_LEX_CSTRING const&, MYSQL_LEX_CSTRING const&, GRANT_INFO*)+0x29d) [0xe31acd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Trigger::execute(THD*)+0x10c) [0xfc150c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Trigger_chain::execute_triggers(THD*)+0x18) [0xfc28b8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Table_trigger_dispatcher::process_triggers(THD*, enum_trigger_event_type, enum_trigger_action_time_type, bool)+0x46) [0xfbc4a6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(fill_record_n_invoke_before_triggers(THD*, COPY_INFO*, mem_root_deque<Item*> const&, mem_root_deque<Item*> const&, TABLE*, enum_trigger_event_type, int, bool, bool*)+0x3f9) [0xe45ac9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_insert_values::execute_inner(THD*)+0x454) [0x1352464]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x525) [0xf15695]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0x9f0) [0xeb98d0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Prepared_statement::execute(String*, bool)+0x8f0) [0xee8160]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Prepared_statement::execute_loop(String*, bool)+0x117) [0xeec5f7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysqld_stmt_execute(THD*, Prepared_statement*, bool, unsigned long, PS_PARAM*)+0x181) [0xeecba1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x1712) [0xebfbf2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x19c) [0xec101c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0xfe69e0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x272fc3e]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7ea5) [0x7f09d562bea5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f09d3a0e8dd]



Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f08e5343368): insert into `client_invoices` (`customer_id`, `invoice_date`, `sub_total`, `vat`, `total`, `client_operating_unit_id`, `client_invoice_id`, `invoiced`, `paid`, `created_by`, `updated_by`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (459, '2020-10-18 08:03:01', '24202.53', '0', '24202.53', 1, 0, 0, 0, 47, 47, '2020-10-20 08:03:02', '2020-10-20 08:03:02')
Connection ID (thread ID): 743
Status: NOT_KILLED



The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2020-10-20T06:03:04.667817Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-10-20T06:03:04.668382Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 59229
2020-10-20T06:03:04.685040Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-10-20T06:03:07.357601Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-10-20T06:03:08.537376Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2020-10-20T06:03:08.656148Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-10-20T06:03:08.656724Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-10-20T06:03:08.733111Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22' socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

When I run `SHOW TABLE client_invoices;`, this is the result I get:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `client_invoices` (
 `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `client_invoice_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unique autoincrementing bigint for this client',
 `client_operating_unit_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 `customer_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 `invoice_status_id` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `invoice_date` date NOT NULL,
 `sub_total` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
 `vat` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
 `total` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
 `invoiced` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Invoice sent to customer',
 `paid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Invoice been paid',
 `exported` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `automatic_invoice` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Invoice has been generated automatically',
 `comments` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_by` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `updated_by` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `invoice_id` (`client_operating_unit_id`,`client_invoice_id`),
 KEY `client_invoices_client_operating_unit_id_index` (`client_operating_unit_id`),
 KEY `client_invoices_customer_id_index` (`customer_id`),
 KEY `client_invoices_invoice_status_id_index` (`invoice_status_id`),
 KEY `client_invoices_invoice_date_index` (`invoice_date`),
 CONSTRAINT `client_invoices_client_operating_unit_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`client_operating_unit_id`) REFERENCES `client_operating_units` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
 CONSTRAINT `client_invoices_customer_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
 CONSTRAINT `client_invoices_invoice_status_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`invoice_status_id`) REFERENCES `client_invoice_status` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=60975 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: I am having the same problem with this version of mysql(8.0.22) that was updated yesterday but in my case it is at the time of doing an update. If you find any solution, let me know

Comment: @josemm1790 That's the same version that is giving me a headache. Unfortunately i havent received any pointers yet even from the MySQL forum

Comment: It is the same problem but with another instruction which makes me think that it is not directly tied to query but perhaps to some new configuration parameter...

Comment: Atm I recreated all the triggers (had like 10) and atm it seems working for 5 minutes. Will monitor the situation.

Comment: did not work :/

Comment: I think we should report this as a bug on bugs.mysql.com as one of the users recommended on this post: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,690696,690696#msg-690696

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101257&thanks=4 I already did

Comment: Leo Rams: I think I've stumbled upon a possible cause. If there are no default values specified for a column into which you are making an update/insert within the trigger, it might cause a failure - especially with the DATE and DATETIME types. This causes the trigger to fail without an error and thus resulting maybe into some process that causes mysql daemon to crash and restart.

Comment: @peterC_ In my case, its just a straight insert and i am using the trigger to calculate the column value by getting the maxim value from the DB and adding 1 to it. That particular column does not have a default value, would that cause any issues? After checking the logs i have noticed that the insert does happen at times and at times it fails which may also suggest that there are several factors which are causing the server to restart, apart from the trigger

Comment: @LeoRams This has worked in our case so far: we rename the table where the problem was happening and then we recreate it and so far it has not happened again.

Comment: @josemm1790 Yesterday i dropped all the tables and re imported them again (which should be similar to your suggestion as this creates the tables and the triggers from scratch) but the issue still persists. Is your solution still working, no issue now?

Comment: @LeoRams Yes, on our side everything is fine at the moment, we had the same problem on other table but we did the same and it is working well.

Comment: got the same problem with triggers after updating to 8.0.22, but in my case the trigger fails randomly

Comment: @josemm1790 I also tried dropping and recreating the main table and target table of the trigger, without success.

Comment: @LeoRams        Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE client_invoices;  to allow check off of data types supplied when your INSERT fails.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have updated my answer to include the text results on the query

Comment: @LeoRams  Could you be caught in the whirlwind of newest version going GA?  From what I see, 8.0.22 became GA on 2020-10-19. About 6 days ago. In the future avoid installing anything less than 3 months old to avoid being on the bleeding edge with bug reporting duties.  Questions, A) When the trigger was created, did it include leading DELIMITER $$ and ending DELIMITER: ? B) For your insert into `client_invoices`, B1) invoice_date is a date field and would not expect hh:mm:ss in the string. B2) sub_total, vat, total data values do not need enclosing single quotes for decimal data types.

Comment: @LeoRams       B3) timestamp columns - updated_at and created_at will cause application failure due to out of RANGE data when values are > 2038-01-19 03:14:07. View profile, Network profile for free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Definitely an issue brought forward by the 8.0.22 upgrade. Will look at some of the issues you have raised and see if we can make fixes for them in the hope that we may resolve this...

Comment: Having the same issue, though my datetime column has a default whereas varchar/char columns do not have a default at present (not tested setting a default)

Comment: @MrJ This definitely seems to be a bug with stored routines in 8.0.22 and sadly MySQL is taking their sweet time responding to our bug report

Comment: @LeoRams they’ve just replied to me asking for a test case and said looked like a duplicate of yours and call stacks are similar, submitted my bug report 6hrs ago ... assume you’ve already been asked for test case ... no doubt will take a while for a fix to come out

Comment: @MrJ Yeah, all we can do is wait until we get some indication from them on what the issue is and what our options will be for a fix either on their side or on ours...

Comment: @peterC_ are oracle bug reports private? tried to open your bug report but it only shows `You do not have access to bug #101257.`

Comment: @raphaeldavidf The bug reports were marked as private and their reasoning was because they cause server to crash. I don’t know what that means or what’s the logic behind it

Comment: @LeoRams Any news on the bug report?

Comment: Having the same issue with 8.0.22. MySQL process randomly restarts. We have around 11 triggers and a few had DATETIME non-default. After setting the default, the issue still persists. Any clue how can I debug to get to the root cause and fix it.

Comment: @raphaeldavidf nothing has been said or done on the bug report, its like they dont even care that this is happening sadly...

Comment: @AdityaMertia I would suggest that you share your trigger code and hopefully someone would point you in the right direction. What worked in my case, was removing all the IFNULLs i had in my triggers and that solved the server restart issue...

Answer (score 4):

MySQL 8.0.23 released today (01/18/2021) should fix this issue:

> Bug#32045681: Heap-use-after-free in triggers Item_splocal::this_item()
>
> This problem requires several subsequent sessions to use the same
> trigger procedure, containing a local variable. Since Items are
> prepared only on first installment in the server, and the m_thd member
> of Item_splocal is initialized only on preparation, on second use
> m_thd is different from the current THD and a failure is provoked.
>
> There are at least two ways to fix this problem. One is to assign
> m_thd when binding the procedure to the new session. However, the
> solution may be considered vulnerable and we may risk ending with
> the same problem. The strategy chosen here is to remove the m_thd
> member and use current_thd instead. The existing code warns about it,
> however accessing current_thd as a thread-local variable is
> sufficiently fast now, and the same principle is used several other
> places in the server. Still, passing a THD as context argument would
> be even better, but is far too intrusive for a bugfix.
>
> Reviewed by: Dmitry Lenev Dmitry.Lenev@oracle.com

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/commit/aecc02f8c75beb0f5911b02b8364b4e2ba22a25a

Waiting for Percona release to test it

Comment: thanks for letting us know! Just installed and it seems to have worked, my test trigger that was rebooting the server ran fine

Comment: FYI: Hasn't fixed it for me. Steps I used to reproduce the bug no longer triggered the crash. However, since then I've seen it happen in production (rans MySQL 8.0.23 of course) again.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to track down the problem only to a update trigger (others seems to work just fine).

The strange thing is that this test update trigger works just fine:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `nobreak_status_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `nobreak_status` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE old_values VARCHAR(2000);
    
    SET old_values := '';
    
    
    IF TRUE THEN
        INSERT INTO cybersecurity.nobreak_status_changelog (`date`, `user`, `type`, result, attribute) VALUES (NOW(), USER(), 'UPDATE', '', '');
    END IF;
END
```

while this one crashes the mysql server randomly:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `nobreak_status_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `nobreak_status` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE old_values VARCHAR(2000);
    
    SET old_values := '';
    
    
    IF old_values = '' THEN
        INSERT INTO cybersecurity.nobreak_status_changelog (`date`, `user`, `type`, result, attribute) VALUES (NOW(), USER(), 'UPDATE', '', '');
    END IF;
END
```

UPDATE:

Return from `SHOW CREATE TABLE cybersecurity.nobreak_status_changelog;`

```
CREATE TABLE `nobreak_status_changelog` (
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `result` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `attribute` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

UPDATE 2: Just checked the server logs and these started to show up at least once a day since the update:

```
Oct 29 08:01:50 SERVER systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Oct 29 08:01:50 SERVER systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 29 08:01:50 SERVER systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Oct 29 08:01:50 SERVER systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 12.
Oct 29 08:01:50 SERVER systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Oct 29 08:01:50 SERVER systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Oct 29 08:01:55 SERVER systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE cybersecurity.nobreak_status_changelog; for analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck updated the post with the return from SHOW CREATE TABLE

Comment: Could it be that you need a TABLE LOCK to append to this table with no PRIMARY key?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I dont think so, because the trigger is the only one that writes to that table, so it wouldnt have any kind of racing condition to read/write that data

Comment: @MrJ LeoRams  Are you guys getting these error logs (Update 2) also?

Comment: @raphaeldavidf not seen that where I've looked, what command you running to produce and will take a look?

Comment: @MrJ `grep -r "mysql.service" /var/log/`

Comment: @raphaeldavidf cannot seem to find anything matching

Comment: @MrJ try with `grep -ri "mysql" /var/log/`

Comment: @raphaeldavidf mysqld.service is what I should have used... your first line is essentially the same as mine

Answer (score 1):

Joined this bug-club after update to 8.0.22, which has a numerous security fixes and we had to upgrade. In my case the trigger is after delete:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_n2d_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `n2d` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE vn_state tinyint(1);

    SELECT n_state FROM nets WHERE net_id=OLD.net_id INTO vn_state;
    IF (vn_state=0) THEN
        UPDATE dicts SET hits=hits-1 WHERE d_id=OLD.d_id;
        UPDATE nets SET hits=hits-1 WHERE net_id=OLD.net_id;
    END IF;
END
```

Looking at common denominator, it's like the issue is with accessing the local variables.

Edit: rewrote the trigger dropping the internal variable and see no crashes. My current code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_n2d_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `n2d` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT n_state FROM nets WHERE net_id=OLD.net_id)=0) THEN
        UPDATE dicts SET hits=hits-1 WHERE d_id=OLD.d_id;
        UPDATE nets SET hits=hits-1 WHERE net_id=OLD.net_id;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: I have not finished my tests yet, but I am following your lead "issue is with accessing the local variables" and results are very positive, no crashes after removed variables from trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem after upgrade 5.7 to 8.0.22-13 (Percona Server). Bug was reported in https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-7477

**I tried without success:**

- Turn off replication (disable slave)
- Recreate trigger
- Recreate table
- Remove INSERTs from trigger

@RealEnder suggested that the problem could be in the **use of local variables inside trigger**, so I removed all variables from trigger and no crashes since it.

I still need to find alternatives for not using variables in the trigger, it is not a solution, but a workaround until they fix the bug.

Update1: 24 hours w/o crash

Update2: 11 days w/o crash

Comment: In my case, the issue was resolved by removing the IFNULL function and my trigger still used variables. It seems there are different approaches to coming up with temporary solution to this bug and what works for one may not work for the other

Answer (score 0):

I updated my trigger to the following and that has stopped the MySQL server crashes (its been close to 36 hours now without a restart):

```
CREATE TRIGGER max_client_invoice_before_insert
                        BEFORE INSERT
                           ON client_invoices FOR EACH ROW
                        BEGIN
                           DECLARE vMax int(11);
                           SELECT IF(COUNT(client_invoice_id) > 0, MAX(client_invoice_id) + 1, 1) from client_invoices where client_operating_unit_id = NEW.client_operating_unit_id INTO vMax;
                           SET NEW.client_invoice_id = vMax;
                        END
```

The only difference was removing

```
SELECT IFNULL(max(client_invoice_id),0)
```

and replacing it with

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(client_invoice_id) > 0, MAX(client_invoice_id) + 1, 1)
```

Comment: Good to see you have a workaround :o) They've just verified that what I provided them caused a bug. Unfortunately for me, I do not think I can really alter my trigger statement :o(

Comment: @MrJ Please share your trigger and hopefully someone can provide some pointers on how to go around it. You can also share a link to your bug report as well...

Answer (score 0):

One of my triggers that often causes a crash

```
CREATE TRIGGER `items_insert`
    AFTER INSERT
        ON `items` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE rowcount INT;
        SET rowcount = (SELECT COUNT(*) from entity_log WHERE global_ref=NEW.global_ref LIMIT 1);
        IF (rowcount=0 AND LEFT(NEW.global_ref, 2)="ZZ") THEN
            INSERT INTO entity_log (global_ref, entity_type, server_updated_at) values (NEW.global_ref, "IL", UTC_TIMESTAMP());
        END IF;
    END
```

The table

```
CREATE TABLE `entity_log` (
  `entity_id` int NOT NULL,
  `global_ref` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `entity_type` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `subentity_type` char(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `server_updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Unsure how to resolve this one as it is very simple

My MySQL bug report is referenced at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101342 but MySQL made it private, like other report(s) mentioned in the comments, for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

same problem here.
In my case it looks like it's happening on triggers where I have this select:

```
SET vTipoEvento = '';
SELECT TipoEvento
  INTO vTipoEvento
  FROM evexcl
 WHERE eclid = OLD.IdEsito;
```

which is pretty simple. I don't even know how to rewrite it....
Problems begun with mysql 8.0.22 (ubuntu 20.04.2)

I have lots of triggers and in my case it keeps on rebooting

Comment: Hello, I have seen mysql 8.0.23 has been released. I have not tried it yet. Does anybody know if the bug has been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

you can try change how to call query.

The bug's name is: Prepared statements involving stored programs could cause heap-use-after-free memory problems.

So I tried to change how to call statement and I have changed from prepare to single query. It should help, because query is not execuded as "prepared statement'. I don't know if help now, but I hope it will help for some weeks until Percona 8.0.23 will be available.